# How to extract text between two markers?

Tags: python, text, blogs

I am trying to create a blogging site kind of like medium.com. The only problem I am facing is the headings in the blog. I want to do what stack overflow does with bold text.

```
**text**
```

But I can't seem to figure out how to make this. Sorry if this question is not detailed enough and Thanks for giving this question your time.

Comment: Are you asking how to implement markdown in your website? I think you will need to add a lot more details for us to be able to help you there. We have NO IDEA what you've built so far and how you are implementing the conversion of user's text in your site's markdown to the display in HTML. Are you using any markdown libraries like https://python-markdown.github.io/? Are you rolling your own markdown parser?

Comment: You can do this with a regex, but as mentioned there's no point re-inventing the wheel, just use a markdown parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can find string between two subStrings using python regular expression.

```
import re
s = '**text**'
result = re.search('\*\*(.*)\*\*', s)
print(result.group(1)) #output :==> text
```

you really should learn regular expression .

Comment: thanks this helped. can you recommend any sources to learn regex. like a youtube video or course

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp |||||||||||||||||
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UQQsYXa1EHs |||||||||||||||||
https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp